# escaping quotes in execute insert statment

Tags: postgresql, escaping, quotes

I have a function that has an insert inside within loop.  See the function below.

```
        create temp table temp2 (id serial, other_value uuid);
        CREATE OR REPLACE function verify_uuid() returns varchar AS $$
        declare uu RECORD;
        BEGIN
            FOR uu IN  select * from temp1 
            loop
            execute 'INSERT INTO temp2 values ''' || uu ||''':uuid';
            END LOOP;
        END
        $$
        LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' ;
        select verify_uuid();
```

The problem that I am having is the values part.  With its present setup, I am getting the error:

> QUERY:  INSERT INTO temp2 values
>   '(1,6f32e71c-9aad-48a9-a72c-bdec2f4548a2)':uuid

The quotes are in the wrong place, and I am not sure how to get them in the right place.

Comment: I thought the def of temp1 might be helpful  --                           CREATE temp table temp1 (id serial, some_value varchar);

Comment: Not familiar with PostGre, but your problem is uu is a record. Needs to be something like execute 'INSERT INTO temp2 values (uu.id,''' || uu.uid ||'''):uuid';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in the end, I went with the following.    It got me to this point:

`EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO temp2 values ('||uu.id||','''|| uu.some_value||''')';`

Answer (score 0):

```
execute
    'insert into temp2 (other_value) values ($1)'
    using uu.the_column::uuid;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Comment: I am getting the error ERROR:  column "other_value" is of type uuid but expression is of type character varying
LINE 1: INSERT INTO temp2 (other_value) values ($1)
                                                ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.                       where do you put the ::uuid to type cast?

Comment: @Jeff Edited with the cast.